# combine values from multiple rows and columns into 1 row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the current data frame (**Table A**) where position A and name A (e.g) are a pair. In this data frame, for each Name column, there is only 1 valid value as denoted by the bold values (where Position value is not -1).
I would like to combine these bold values into **Table B** below such that only those names with value  != 1 will be populated. I am stuck what to do. I tried using sql group by but the filter criteria applied result in 0 result. is there any guidance from you please ?

**CURRENT Table A**

| Position A | Name A | Position B | Name B | Position C | Name C | Position D | Name D | Position E | Name E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | tortise | -1 | monkey | **2** | **coca cola** | -1 | slug | -1 | rooster |
| **3** | **sprite** | **2** | **coffee** | -1 | bird | -1 | monkey | -1 | ostrich |
| -1 | nope | -1 | nope | -1 | fish | **5** | **root beer** | **1** | **tea** |
| -1 | nope | -1 | nope | -1 | nope | -1 | nope | -1 | nope |

**DESIRED TABLE B**

| Name A | Name B | Name C | Name D | Name E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **sprite** | **coffee** | **coca cola** | **root beer** | **tea** |

Comment: What dataframe library are you using, Pandas? Please [edit] to add the tag for it and show us the code you tried. BTW, if you want more tips, see [ask] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Please share your code with us so we can help.

Comment: You have only one record in the output?

Answer (score 0):

As you have paired `Position/Name` columns, [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)ed `Name`s can be filtered by stacked `Position`s (which values differ from `-1`), then converted back to a daraframe form:

```
new_df = (df.filter(like='Name').stack()
          .where(df.filter(like='Position').stack().ne(-1).values)
          .dropna().droplevel(0).sort_index().to_frame().T
)
```

---

```
    Name A   Name B      Name C     Name D  Name E
0   sprite   coffee   coca cola  root beer     tea
```